# Using JavaCV in Jython

Tags: python, user-interface, opencv, jython

Has anyone successfully imported into Jython the JavaCV implementation of OpenCV? I have a project that needs to be written in Python and needs heavy GUI development. The standard GUI tools in native Python are not adequate and neither are many of the additional modules for GUIs. I know that Java Swing and SWT will work fantastically for my project, but I happen to also require some deep image processing and computer vision algorithms to be used within the GUI I am creating. Jython seems like a perfect fit, allowing access to Java Swing, but I need to know how to get JavaCV to work specifically in Jython.

Answer (score 0):

I don't answer on the quality of JavaCV, but I can point you out on a project that may contain answers to your question as it uses Java, Jython and OpenCV multi platform. this is [project Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/docx/devs/system-design.html)